# put listing in tikzpicture

Tags: latex, tex, tikz

I use the following code to create a box for equations. It uses Tikz to create the box.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}%      pour les maths
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\mybox}[4][\textwidth-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-2mm]{%
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[line width=.5mm, rounded corners, draw=#2, inner ysep=10pt, text width=#1, outer sep=0] (one) {\vspace*{15pt}\\\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#4\end{varwidth}};
\node[text=white,anchor=north east,align=center, minimum height=20pt] (two) at (one.north east) {#3 \hspace*{.5mm}};
\path[fill=#2] 
    (one.north west|-two.west) --
    ($(two.west)+(-1.5cm,0)$) 
    to[out=0,in=180] (two.south west) --
    (two.south east) [rounded corners] --
    (one.north east) -- 
    (one.north west) [sharp corners] -- cycle;
\node[text=white,anchor=north east,align=center, minimum height=20pt, text height=2ex] (three) at (one.north east) {#3 \hspace*{.5mm}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\mybox{green!70!black}{The Caption}{
\begin{enumerate}
\item Show that\\
$\displaystyle D_2f(x,y) = \frac{\partial {}}{\partial{y}} \biggl( \int_0^xg_1 (t,0) \ dt + \int_0^y g_2(x,s) \ ds \biggr)$
\item prove that\\
$\displaystyle \biggl(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}  \biggr)\biggl(\forall y \in \mathbb{R} \biggr) x\neq y\, \text{ and } \, x+y \neq 2 \implies x^{2}-2x \neq y^2-2y$ 
\end{enumerate}

}
\end{document}
```

but Now I want to put listing inside the box
When I put the listing inside the mbox I got an error

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
fun1 <- function(data, data.frame, graph=TRUE, limit=20, ...) {
[omitted statements]
if (graph)
par(pch="*", ...)
[more omissions]
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

the error is

```
! Argument of \lst@next has an extra }.
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use listings inside arguments directly. You either need to escape and properly prepare the verbatim code or store it somewhere else. See section 6.1 of [the listing manual](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for more information.

**Store the listing in a box**

```
\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\mylisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
fun1 <- function(data, data.frame, graph=TRUE, limit=20, ...) {
[omitted statements]
if (graph)
par(pch="*", ...)
[more omissions]
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\mybox{green!70!black}{The Caption}{
  \usebox\mylisting
}
\end{document}
```

**Store the listing in an external file**

```
\lstinputlisting{external_file.R}
```

**Add line feeds `^^J`**

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]^^J
fun1 <- function(data, data.frame, graph=TRUE, limit=20, ...) {^^J
[omitted statements]^^J
if (graph)^^J
par(pch="*", ...)^^J
[more omissions]^^J
}^^J
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

Note: You will probably need to resize your box for that long first line of code.

Comment: I needed a `\newsavebox{\mylisting}` before the `\begin{lrbox}....` to get it to work.